# How to create a custom post type that contains another custom post type?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I want to create a custom post type 'A', which will contain multiple post types of post type 'B', and custom post type 'A' is a series of post type 'B', so I'd like the edit page of post type 'A' to be similar to the wordpress view posts section with add/edit/delete buttons but only showing post types of 'B' that are attached to the post  of type 'A'.

Is there an easy or somewhat easy way to do this?

Comment: Please update your answer to be easy or somewhat easy to understand. Post types contained within post types does not necessarily speak to WordPress native functionality.